# Index a document and perform analyses on its term vector

Tags: c#, .net, lucene

I have the following scenario: I create a lucene document from a potentially very large text. Apart from indexing the text, I perform some analysis on the document for which I need the document's term frequency vector. The results of this analysis also need to be stored in the lucene document/index. Here is my current approach:

With the following method I compute the text's term vector (`_analyzer` is an instance of some `Lucene.Net.Analysis.Analyzer`):

```
public Dictionary<string, int> GetTermVector(string text)
{
    var termVector = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(text))
    {
       var tokenStream = _analyzer.TokenStream("", stringReader);
       var charTermAttribute = tokenStream.GetAttribute<ITermAttribute>();

       while (tokenStream.IncrementToken())
       {
           var term = charTermAttribute.Term;

           if (termVector.ContainsKey(term)) termVector[term]++;
           else termVector.Add(term, 1);
       }

       return termVector;
    }
}
```

The above method is used by a method which basically sends the 500 most frequent terms to a webservice and returns the results.

```
public static class CategorizationService
{
    private static ScoringServiceClient _service;

    public static Dictionary<Guid, double> Categorize(string text, Language language)
    {
        var tokenizer = language ==  Language.English
            ? new StringTokenizer(new PrimaryAnalyzer())
            : new StringTokenizer(new PrimaryAnalyzer("German"));

        var termVector = tokenizer
            .GetTermVector(text)
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.Value)
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value)
            .Take(500);

        // Create string representation of the term vector which is consumed by webservice
        var termVectorString = termVector.Aggregate(string.Empty, (s, pair) => s + $"{pair.Key};{pair.Value}\n");

        try
        {
            var isoLanguageString = language == Language.English ? "en" : "de";
            if (_service == null) _service = new ScoringServiceClient();
            _service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = Program.UserName;
            _service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Program.UserPassword;
            var categories = _service.Categorize(termVectorString, isoLanguageString);
            return categories;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            _service.SafeDispose();
            _service = null;
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Afterwards, everything is packaged into a lucene document which I add to the index. Last step is committing the index changes. Here is the method which calls the analysis and creates the document:

```
var itemContent = ReadItemContent();
var deContent = language == Language.German ? itemContent : string.Empty;
var enContent = language == Language.English ? itemContent : string.Empty;

try
{
    categories = CategorizationService.Categorize(itemContent, language);
    isCategorized = true;
}
catch (Exception) {}

// Transform analysis results into an indexable string        
var categoriesString = categories.Aggregate(string.Empty, (seed, categorization) => $"{seed} \r\n {categorization.Key} {categorization.Value}");

var document = new Document();
document.Add(new Field("Id", $"localfile:{Guid.NewGuid()}", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.YES)); 
// More field added here
Console.WriteLine("Adding document...");
// In this step, lucene analyzes the document again
_writer.AddDocument(document);
Console.WriteLine("Commiting index...");
_writer.Commit();
Console.WriteLine("Reopening reader...");
_reader = _reader.Reopen();
Console.WriteLine("Reading term vector");
```

Obviously there is some wastage involved in this approach. I am now thinking about how to avoid running the analyzer over the entire text twice (first time for my own analysis, second for indexing the document). That would mean, however, that I need to index the document first, then perform my own analysis and then update the document to contain the analysis results. I am not sure if this leads to a double indexing again...

So what are your ideas to perform this operation flow as efficiently as possible?

Comment: @Heslacher: It returns a Dictionary<Guid, double>. In the method above I simply return the webservice's return value.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing `Dictionary.ContainsKey()` if the value will be used is hurting my eyes.

Please use `TryGetValue()` like so

```
public Dictionary<string, int> GetTermVector(string text)
{
    var termVector = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(text))
    {
       var tokenStream = _analyzer.TokenStream("", stringReader);
       var charTermAttribute = tokenStream.GetAttribute<ITermAttribute>();

       while (tokenStream.IncrementToken())
       {
           var term = charTermAttribute.Term;
           int value;
           termVector.TryGetValue(term, out value);
           termVector[term] = value + 1;
       }

       return termVector;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Any ideas regarding the question?

Answer (score 2):

I think this part can be optimized:

> ```
> var termVector = tokenizer
>   .GetTermVector(text)
>   .OrderByDescending(p => p.Value)
>   .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value)
>   .Take(500);
> ```

in a way that you first take the 500 items and push them into a dictionary instead of craeting a dictionary for the entire collection and then getting only the first 500 items:

```
var termVector = tokenizer
    .GetTermVector(text)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Value)
    .Take(500)
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
```

A minor one but perhaps it makes a difference ;-)

---

Also this section is not the prittiest:

> ```
> var tokenizer = language ==  Language.English
>   ? new StringTokenizer(new PrimaryAnalyzer())
>   : new StringTokenizer(new PrimaryAnalyzer("German"));
> ```

why not simply like this?

```
var tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(new PrimaryAnalyzer(language.ToString()));
```

---

And another one:

> ```
> var isoLanguageString = language == Language.English ? "en" : "de";
> ```

I think you should either create a dictionary for it or create custom attributes for the enum:

```
enum Language
{
    [TwoLetterIsoCode("en")]
    English,

    [TwoLetterIsoCode("de")]
    German
}
```

For more information about enums and custom attributes refer to [How to get Custom Attribute values for enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097766/how-to-get-custom-attribute-values-for-enums) on Stack Overflow.

With a small extension method you could then do the following

```
var isoLanguageString = language.GetTwoLetterIsoCode();
```

---

There is also a line that has misleading names in it:

> ```
> var categoriesString = categories.Aggregate(string.Empty, (seed, categorization) => $"{seed} \r\n {categorization.Key} {categorization.Value}");
> ```

You call it `seed` but it's not a seed, here the `string.Empty` is the seed and your seed is the current value (accumulator).

> ```
>  public static TAccumulate Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate>(
>        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
>        TAccumulate seed,
>        Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func)
> ```